# Send a List to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java

[This is my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdOaE.png)

I want to update in relativaly "real-time" let's say every 10 seconds or so... the badge that says approved will say the getStatus()

My problem is that i need to fetch data from a List and I have no idea how to send all this data to the JavaScript file.

`runningContainers` is a List and i need to get `runningContainers.getName()` and `runningContainer.getStatus()` for every one in the list and send it to the javascript.

***I just need a way to pass all the data to the javascript so I can update the badges relativally to that name.***

Java

```
  try {

            DockerClientConfig config = DefaultDockerClientConfig.createDefaultConfigBuilder()
                    .withDockerHost("tcp://localhost:2375")
                    .withDockerConfig("/")
                    //.withRegistryUsername("profile")
                    //.withRegistryPassword("profile")
                    .build();

            DockerClient dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance(config).build();

            List<Container> runningContainers = dockerClient.listContainersCmd()
                    .exec();
```

JavaScript

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'Containers',         
        success: function () {

        },
        error: function() {

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Serialize your list of objects to JSON. I like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)